# Trying to run mvn exec and getting mojo exception on plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So I am running

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=”com.utm.csc.HTMLParser” -Dexec.args=”http://www.simplehtmlguide.com”
```

for my Java project. It runs in Eclipse but with the command above, gives me the following errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building assignment1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ assignment1 ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ”com.utm.csc.HTMLParser”
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.064 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-24T16:17:21-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-    plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project assignment1: An exception occured while executing the Java class. ”com.utm.csc.HTMLParser” -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is an image of my paths

[image]

I am using OS X El Capitan on a 64-bit MacBook Air mid-2012. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are giving the argument incorrectly. Your command should be:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.utm.csc.HTMLParser -Dexec.args=http://www.simplehtmlguide.com
```

Notice the lack of quotes. This can be hinted from the error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: `”com.utm.csc.HTMLParser”`

means that somehow, Java searched for a class called `”com.utm.csc.HTMLParser”` but it didn't find any, simply because it is actually named `com.utm.csc.HTMLParser`, without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to compile first. `exec:java` doesn't do it by default.

```
mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=”com.utm.csc.HTMLParser” -Dexec.args=”http://www.simplehtmlguide.com”
```